# Keras Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been training my model by feeding the `fit()` method with train and test generators from the data that is stored away in hdf5 files (approx. 25,000 images and labels). I have recently processed negative cases into a new hdf5 file with a similar amount of images, however, after updating the generator to read from both files, grab half the batch size amount of images from each set, and merge them together, the training crashes with `Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)` after a single epoch.

I have made sure that my model output, generator output, and data types are all correct (model: UNet, sigmoid, classes=1, output shape = (...,1), output type = bool) as other answers of the same issue suggest, yet I am still getting the same error.

**train.py**

```
db = h5py.File(db_output_path, 'r')
a = db['data'][200]
b = db['labels'][200]

db_neg = h5py.File(db_negatives_path, 'r')
train_neg_gen = kfold.split(db_neg['data'])
neg_idx = []
for t in train_neg_gen:
    neg_idx.append(t)
batch_size=16

for train, test in kfold.split(db['data'], db['labels']):
    
    train_neg_idx, test_neg_idx = neg_idx[fold_no-1]
    
    gen_train = create_hdf5_generator(db_output_path, train, batch_size, CLASSES, db_negatives_path, train_neg_idx)   
    gen_val = create_hdf5_generator(db_output_path, test, batch_size, CLASSES, db_negatives_path, test_neg_idx)
    model.load_weights('weights/weights_2022-11-20.h5')
    
    # Generate a print
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')
    
    steps_per_epoch = (2*len(train))//batch_size
    validation_steps= (2*len(test))//batch_size
    
    results = model.fit(gen_train,
                        epochs=10, validation_data=gen_val,
                        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                        validation_steps=validation_steps,
                        callbacks=callbacks)
        
    # Increase fold number
    fold_no = fold_no + 1
```

**Generator**

```
def create_hdf5_generator(db_path, indices, batch_size, classes, neg_db_path=None, neg_indices=None):
    db = h5py.File(db_path)
    neg_db = h5py.File(neg_db_path)
    
    while True:
        if neg_indices is not None:
            skip = batch_size//2
            restart = 0
            for i in np.arange(0, len(indices), skip):
                j = i
                #j tracks neg_db indices which is smaller in size than positive indices tracked by i
                if i >= len(neg_indices):
                    j = restart
                    restart += skip
                    
                images = db['data'][indices[i:i+skip]]
                labels = db['labels'][indices[i:i+skip]]
                
                neg_images = neg_db['data'][neg_indices[j:j+skip]]
                neg_labels = np.zeros(labels.shape).astype(np.float32)
                
                images_concat = np.concatenate((images, neg_images), axis=0)
                labels_concat = np.concatenate((labels, neg_labels), axis=0)
                
                np.random.seed(123)
                np.random.shuffle(images_concat)
                np.random.seed(123)
                np.random.shuffle(labels_concat)
                
                
                yield images_concat, labels_concat.astype(bool)
```

**console output**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Training for fold 1 ...
Epoch 1/10
2773/2774 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1157 - mean_io_u_2: 0.4766  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Noam\github\proj\train.py", line 181, in <module>
    results = model.fit(gen_train,

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1214, in fit
    val_logs = self.evaluate(

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1489, in evaluate
    tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 924, in _call
    results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3023, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1960, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 591, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(

  File "C:\Users\Noam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
     [[node binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul (defined at C:\Users\Noam\github\proj\train.py:181) ]]
     [[confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_12/_33]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
     [[node binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul (defined at C:\Users\Noam\github\proj\train.py:181) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_test_function_79850]

Function call stack:
test_function -> test_function



2022-11-27 19:22:08.581553: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.055899: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.073779: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 82 deviceMemorySize: 24.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 871.81GiB/s
2022-11-27 19:22:18.073819: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.093917: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.093939: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.100311: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.102617: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.105904: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.111640: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.112034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:18.112100: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-11-27 19:22:18.112463: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-11-27 19:22:18.113094: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 82 deviceMemorySize: 24.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 871.81GiB/s
2022-11-27 19:22:18.113127: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-11-27 19:22:18.495306: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-11-27 19:22:18.495334: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 
2022-11-27 19:22:18.495341: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N 
2022-11-27 19:22:18.495486: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21670 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2022-11-27 19:22:21.753068: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2022-11-27 19:22:23.357640: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:23.868767: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:359] Loaded cuDNN version 8201
2022-11-27 19:22:24.730172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2022-11-27 19:22:25.324257: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2022-11-27 19:23:30.675901: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 19:29:53.026090: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 19:46:47.257803: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 19:50:09.871857: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 19:51:28.339643: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 20:22:00.445508: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 20:30:20.786297: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 20:45:59.779202: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2022-11-27 21:06:14.203518: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
```

**UNet**

```
sigmoid
binary_crossentropy
Model: "model_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 128, 128, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_57 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 896         input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_27 (Dropout)            (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           conv2d_57[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_58 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 9248        dropout_27[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_58[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_59 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   18496       max_pooling2d_12[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_28 (Dropout)            (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_59[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_60 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       dropout_28[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 32, 32, 64)   0           conv2d_60[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_61 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_13[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_29 (Dropout)            (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           conv2d_61[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_62 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  147584      dropout_29[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 16, 16, 128)  0           conv2d_62[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_63 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_14[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_30 (Dropout)            (None, 16, 16, 256)  0           conv2d_63[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_64 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 256)  590080      dropout_30[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 8, 8, 256)    0           conv2d_64[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_65 (Conv2D)              (None, 8, 8, 512)    1180160     max_pooling2d_15[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_31 (Dropout)            (None, 8, 8, 512)    0           conv2d_65[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_66 (Conv2D)              (None, 8, 8, 512)    2359808     dropout_31[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_12 (Conv2DTran (None, 16, 16, 256)  524544      conv2d_66[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_12 (Concatenate)    (None, 16, 16, 512)  0           conv2d_transpose_12[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_64[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_67 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 256)  1179904     concatenate_12[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_32 (Dropout)            (None, 16, 16, 256)  0           conv2d_67[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_68 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 256)  590080      dropout_32[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_13 (Conv2DTran (None, 32, 32, 128)  131200      conv2d_68[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_13 (Concatenate)    (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           conv2d_transpose_13[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_62[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_69 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  295040      concatenate_13[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_33 (Dropout)            (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           conv2d_69[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_70 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  147584      dropout_33[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_14 (Conv2DTran (None, 64, 64, 64)   32832       conv2d_70[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_14 (Concatenate)    (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           conv2d_transpose_14[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_60[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_71 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   73792       concatenate_14[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_34 (Dropout)            (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_71[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_72 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       dropout_34[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_15 (Conv2DTran (None, 128, 128, 32) 8224        conv2d_72[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_15 (Concatenate)    (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           conv2d_transpose_15[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_58[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_73 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 18464       concatenate_15[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_35 (Dropout)            (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           conv2d_73[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_74 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 9248        dropout_35[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_75 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 1)  33          conv2d_74[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 7,760,097
Trainable params: 7,760,097
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, the error lied in one of the output shapes from the generator.
I was always guaranteeing that `neg_labels` to have the same shape as `labels` even though `neg_images` might not on the zeroth axis.

The fix was to set the shape of `neg_labels` to `neg_images`'s shape on the first three axes and `labels` last axis:

```
neg_images = neg_db['data'][neg_indices[j:j+skip]]
neg_labels = np.zeros((neg_images.shape[0],neg_images.shape[1],neg_images.shape[2],labels.shape[3])).astype(np.float32)
```